# C# perform action if and only if multiple events are fired simultaneously

Tags: c#, event-handling

I have an event class that looks like this:

```
public delegate void OnEventTriggered();

public interface IEventClause
{
    event OnEventTriggered onEventTriggered;
}
```

and another class that has a list of Events:

```
class Behaviour
{
    IEnumerable<IEventClause> EventClauses { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<IConditionClause> ConditionClauses { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<IActionClause> ActionClauses { get; set; }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        foreach (IEventClause eventClause in EventClauses)
        {
            eventClause.onEventTriggered += OnEventTriggered;
        }
    }

    public void OnEventTriggered()
    {
        //TODO: OR, needs to figure a way to simulates AND
        if (IsAllConditionsSatisfied())
        {
            RunAllActions();
        }
    }

}
```

Right now, all OnEventTriggered of the EventClauses will be listened by OnEvenTriggered on the Behaviour class, and this creates an OR effect, and I'm looking for an AND effect. How can I do this?

One way that I can think of is to have the events set a flag and use a polling mechanism to check if all the flags set by the events are true. I think it should be doable without explicitly polling(which I think is not neat) but I can't figure out how.

This is what I'd like to recreate: http://world-editor-tutorials.thehelper.net/triggers.php

but with the triggers getting fired only when all the events are met

Comment: Do you *mean* simultaneously, or do you mean "once each event has been seen once", which could of course occur over a long (for a computer) period of time. Can the same event happen more than once, and what should happen then?

Comment: And even if you mean "simultaneously", just how simultaneous do you mean? If the three events fire within a millisecond of each other, does that count? What about a whole second?

Comment: Simultaneity is a dodgy concept when it comes to computers. I would set a time threshold in which all events must fire.

Comment: @JonSkeet hmm.. seems like I can't get away without implementing a timer to poll ya?

Comment: I didn't say that - I'm just asking for clearer requirements.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I'm thinking somewhere along the line of: when alt is hold(true) and left mouse button is down(true) then something will happen. If alt is no longer held(false) and the left mouse button is pressed(true) then it will not do anything.

Comment: Right, so that sounds like you need separate events for "press" and "release". It's not a matter of *timing* at all.